# How I can save my layout on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: My VS Code layout]

The idea behind this question, is have my document upfront, right on the sidebar, a split between files and upload to GitHub, and down below the terminal, in all projects starting now, I open every time my projects! I saw different questions on the platform, but didn't accurate answer to that, I thought.
Thanks,
Miguel.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By default, it keeps the same screen.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) which explains that in VS Code there are 2 modes for saving a setup of IDE - user settings and workspace settings.
Your modifications were probably saved in current workspace so when you open a fresh instance of VS Code by default you are using global user settings.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into it, right now! Have a great day and thanks to make my job easier!